# C# No file access in Windows 8.1 App

Tags: c#, json

In my Windows 8.1 app I want to write to Json file in my datamodel. (See image 1).
I have a button click event with the following code:

```
Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///DataModel/SampleData.json");
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "sampletext");
```

But I receive an UnauthorizedAccessException after pressing the button. (See image 2). 
Is there a way to access to Json file for writing purposes?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: Windows applications should have a manifest which specifies what system resources the app needs, you need to specify file access in there.